# Неправильный sql запрос

Tags: python, база-данных, sql

Не работает sql команда в KInterbasDB (привожу часть программы для анализа)

```
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'D:/ThirdTask/test.db' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'")  
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/ThirdTask/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')  
cur=con.cursor() 
s="""
     create table CLIENTS
      (
        ID   FMTBCD PRIMARY KEY,
        COMPANY   CHAR(50),
        LAST NAME   CHAR(50),
        FIRST NAME   CHAR(50),
        E-MAIL ADDRESS   CHAR(50),
        JOB TITLE   CHAR(50),
        BUSINESS PHONE   CHAR(25),
        HOME PHONE   CHAR(25),
        MOBILE PHONE   CHAR(25),
        FAX NUMBER   CHAR(25),
        ADDRESS   MEMO,
        CITY   CHAR(50),
        STATE/PROVINCE   CHAR(50),
        ZIP/POSTAL CODE   CHAR(15),
        COUNTRY/REGION   CHAR(50),
        WEB-SITE   CHAR(25),
        NOTES   MEMO,
        INCLUDING   BLOB
       )
"""
print s
cur.execute(s)
con.close()
conn.close()
```

Выдает ошибку

```
create table CLIENTS
(
  ID   FMTBCD PRIMARY KEY,
  COMPANY   CHAR(50),
  LAST NAME   CHAR(50),
  FIRST NAME   CHAR(50),
  E-MAIL ADDRESS   CHAR(50),
  JOB TITLE   CHAR(50),
  BUSINESS PHONE   CHAR(25),
  HOME PHONE   CHAR(25),
  MOBILE PHONE   CHAR(25),
  FAX NUMBER   CHAR(25),
  ADDRESS   MEMO,
  CITY   CHAR(50),
  STATE/PROVINCE   CHAR(50),
  ZIP/POSTAL CODE   CHAR(15),
  COUNTRY/REGION   CHAR(50),
  WEB-SITE   CHAR(25),
  NOTES   MEMO,
  INCLUDING   BLOB
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 119, in <module>
    cur.execute(s)
ProgrammingError: (-104, 'isc_dsql_prepare: \n  Dynamic SQL Error\n  SQL error code = -104\n  Token unknown - line 6, column 16\n  CHAR')
```

Comment: Я не претендую, на знатока конкретно этой СУБД, но разве в SQL запросе имена столбцов могут без кавычек быть написаны с пробелами и слешами? Попробуйте заменить их на _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите в двойные кавычки имена, содержащие пробелы, "-" и "/".

Comment: @msi, после этого изменения выдает ошибку 
    ProgrammingError: (-607, 'isc_dsql_prepare: \n  Dynamic SQL Error\n  SQL error code = -607\n  Invalid command\n  Specified domain or source column FMTBCD does not exist')

Comment: @msi, FMTBCD - это тип ключа в sqlite. Он был записан на некотром этапе в json,  а как указать ключ в Firebird?

Comment: Ну, так оставьте его как есть.
У вас же ошибки, судя по сообщению, начинаются со следующей строки.

Answer (score 0):

В любой SQL-базе да и в любой другой приличной системе программирования идентификаторы - одно слово. Соединяйте слова в идентификаторе например, символами подчеркивания или капитализацией:
нельзя  LAST NAME   CHAR(50) 
можно так LAST_NAME   CHAR(50) 
или так LastName   CHAR(50)

Comment: @renegator, после изменения от @msi выдает ошибку ProgrammingError: (-607, 'isc_dsql_prepare: \n Dynamic SQL Error\n SQL error code = -607\n Invalid command\n Specified domain or source column FMTBCD does not exist')

Comment: так исправьте все неправильно поименованные колонки, их у вас много.
эта строка "ID   FMTBCD PRIMARY KEY" вообще неправильная. кроме некорректного имени, тут не указан тип колонки. должно быть что-то вроде "ID_FMTBCD INT PRIMARY KEY"

Comment: FMTBCD - это тип ключа в sqllite. Как указать ключ в Firebird, @renegator?

Comment: Смотрите документацию на слово CONSTRAINT. А для начала добейтесь просто создания таблицы даже без первичного ключа

Comment: > FMTBCD - это тип ключа в sqllite.
Если это счетчик, то поищите в документации как его задать в Firebird. Может быть что-то типа sequence, identity, counter.